# file rewriting with boost?

Tags: c++, boost, file-io

I would like to avoid using CreateFileMapping/MapViewOfFile to rewrite part of a file.  Does boost provide this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Memory-Mapped Files](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html)